# DateTime.TryParseExact(..... out var date) fails to build without errors, but (... out date) builds fine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

In an ASP.NET MVC project, I'm targeting .Net 4.7, and in trying to use the new features in C#7, I'm getting an odd silent failure to build.

I have the following method:

```
public class DateIsValid: ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(value), "d MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            return date > DateTime.Now;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

This builds and runs fine, without any warnings or errors.

But, if I try to use the "out var xxx" as added in C#7, it fails to build, but does not throw any exceptions or show any errors or warnings:

```
public class DateIsValid: ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(value), "d MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out var date))
            return date > DateTime.Now;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Figuring this was just buginess in VS 2017, I tried restarting, but that did not help.  Is there a problem with what I wrote, or is this a bug that should be submitted to the VS team?

In this same project, I'm getting the same silent failure on `ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out var item)`, but using the older pattern works fine:

```
    int res;
    if (x.TryDequeue(out res))
    {
        res++;
    }
```

Comment: The code you've posted works fine for me. Are you sure you're actually using C# 7? Can you use other C# 7 features, e.g. does `if (value is DateTime dt) { return dt > DateTime.UtcNow; }` work? (By the way, using `DateTime.Now` in a web application is a really bad idea - why do you want the result to depend on the server time zone?)

Comment: Thank you, @JonSkeet.  I was targeting .Net 4.7, so I think I was using C#7 (Intellisense seemed happy with my usage).  But this did point me in the right direction: the fix was to run the following in package manager: `Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers` as suggested [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/23/how-to-enable-c-7-in-visual-studio-2017/](here)

Comment: Targeting a specific version of the framework isn't the same as using a specific compiler. I'd normally expect VS 2017 projects to use C# 7 by default, but depending on where you put your code, perhaps it was being compiled by ASP.NET after deployment? Odd.

Comment: @K_foxer9 if you open an existing project in VS 2017 it won't switch to C# 7 by itself. You have to change the target language in the project's Build Settings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and @jonskeet are correct, in that the issue was with the compiler I was using.  The server for the app was just the local machine running in debug.  I created the project in VS2017, and by default it targeted .Net 4.6.2. Based on both of your suggestions, I did change the build settings to use C#7 (instead of default), but that threw a new error : `CS1617: Invalid option '7' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6`. Ultimately, (re)installing the compiler (from my comment above) resolved all of the issues. Thank you both very much!

Comment: You probably should add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wound up being with the compiler.  The project was created as an ASP.NET MVC project targeting .Net 4.5.2 (not 4.6.2, typo above), and when I changed the target framework to 4.7 and tried to use C#7 features, that's when things went wrong.  I had this problem on multiple dev machines, and I tried a few things, but the only fix that worked was also the simplest and quickest: reinstall the compiler:
In Package Manager Console, run `Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers`.  It was suggested that I post the solutions as an answer, so here goes.  Special thanks to @jonskeet and @PanagiotisKanavos for identifying the issue (in the comments above).

Interestingly, changing just the compiler version in advanced build settings did not help.  I've also migrated WPF projects to C#7 on the same machines without issue, so it was odd that this problem cropped up with ASP.NET, but the compiler reinstall was simple and painless.